# How to find latest Typings definitions?

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-typings

When using Typings for Typescript, I find that upgrading libraries frequently causes typings to be flagged as deprecated. However, the warning when running `npm install` simply says that a given typings item is deprecated.

I've searched for days now, and found nothing about how to find out what the new version of a given typings definition is. `typings view someTypingsDef` consistently throws a 404 error.

Does anyone have any idea how to manage this?? It seems *incredibly* unintuitive.

Comment: which item did you try?

Comment: I've tried searching all of the definitely typed repository for hints... but you really can't try anything if you don't have a clue what to do. That's what I'm asking for help on...?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking to an answer to this, typings as a concept is sort of being folded into NPM per the Typescript team.
All typings are now (or are soon to be) wrapped up in the npm `@types` prefix.
For instance, if you need typings for Webpack:

`npm install @types/webpack --save-dev`

Or jQuery:
`npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`

and so on and so forth.